# (JQuery) how to set a event in plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I've tried a simple 'plugin' in jQ like this:

```
$.fn.Lister = function(){
    var container = this;

    // Get some data
    $.get('xxxx', function(result){  

        // foreach result, fill in container. each result item fills as a button.
        $(result).each(function(){  
            $(container).append('<button>'+ this.Name +'</button>');
        });
    });
}
```

then i call this in my page:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#container').Lister();
    });
</script>
```

it's works~ nice work to me, for first time try.

but a problem comes: how to collect value when click a <button> ?

in uploadify plugin, a file selected event settled like this:

```
$('#fileUploader').uploadify({ 
         'onSelect' : function(file){ alert(file.name); } 
});
```

how simulate this in my Lister() like below?

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#container').Lister({
            'onButtonClicked' : function(buttonText) { alert(buttonText); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$.fn.Lister = function(options){
    var container = this;

    if(jQuery.isFunction(options.onButtonClicked)){
        container.on('click', 'button', options.onButtonClicked)
    }

    // Get some data
    $.get('xxxx', function(result){  

        // foreach result, fill in container. each result item fills as a button.
        $(result).each(function(){  
            $(container).append('<button>'+ this.Name +'</button>');
        });
    });
}
```

Then

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#container').Lister({
        'onButtonClicked' : function(e) { alert($(this).text()); }
    });
});
```

Comment: learned. i'll try more complex based on your help, thank you very much.